# All files of GIT repository are marked as "missing" and "new file" at the same time [SourceTree]

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I use GIT 2.17.1 and Sourcetree 2.6.9. In my uncommitted changes all files of my repository are marked as `missing` and also marked `added new` at the same time. I am sure, that I have not moved nor edited those files. They are listet with the same path.

Here is a screenshot of some of the files
[image: sourcetree screenshot]

Edit: "git status" showed the same files as above marked as "missing" and "new file". Each file listed as staged and not staged.

The error occured after the update from SourceTree Version 1.X to 2.6.9

Comment: can you show the "git status" result by command line?

Comment: see my edit above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git reset` did solve the problem.

no idea how the problem initially occured but it seems an old repository state (where these files did not yet exist) was staged somehow. But the state of the files was not changed.